# Typescript: Dynamically assign static object to class instance of super and generate proper type definition files

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, typescript-class

Facing issue in generating types when migrating javascript code to typescript. Maybe I am missing something trivial. typescript playground code is embedded.

[typescript playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/PTAEFMDsBMAcHsCWkAuA6FBnAUAYwDYCGmmoAojAsigN7aigCuATvgFyiYrPIDm9oXPEhdmjXCnjNQACgBGxcAFVWHUXwA0ASlB0GDFAAtEmNC3ygAvKAAGAEhoLMy1gF9gDyIQC24UAB9-UCMTDABPWHBXGwFXAV5wFBV8GWZ4RhRwNW4+HRkdPX1mRJZIWwcQ03N3BzSMqJiGOLjsEFBCWEQMHAJiUgBBTsKGLkIURFxQJxd2ThzIXgBuARGUMYmISiRUTA4aAG0AaVBkUABrcDD4ADNQABUAXQ5CSDDXZf1BYVFxSWZ83QrfRCEQoXRTRTJDSbODbLCgVxWWSVNAgn4SKTtUgoCLgG6gQaILRAhhosFQWHUACSoJeuHApGsAHk5AArcASNBQHIMmQUqg7LRoYrQcTgGQyZCjSD03bg-ZeXzZHgLJ7tV4I6EKnzgaEAN0I+EY4DV+3UC2hLzCDx0lgAfIDPk6TrSZQztb4HkjIOAAO7kLbUeSQ1jE50MYooUou6Wykma3SuMNOlnszl9RC8SAySrQ-lwmmxhnJprYFptRKwYDFBDMLDdPBEEigABK4Fr8PAAA9MjBSBRKahHXN1pNzEiAORtjuYCfxRLTqTwmTQBmZyBU6AFIGR6MohJJVgrtdZzfJ5rYVpgSvAZCrrsN3rNsgoWAQHsUgadYejcaTabJJOwCwEQkCQHwwAdIgwB6gAjMAc6rKOMICvC1jDKANZLnKi51jgpZxN2HagKu1yEIw+Bgj6-ovrA+SXleTCYIQCSgNglbCu22FoAeuFYDIE6wQATAAzAALBOxIMUAA)

Following is the file structure.

```
// endpoint.ts
class Endpoint{
  url: string
  constructor (baseUrl: string,) {
    this.url = `${baseUrl}/${name || this.type}`
  }
  getUrl(route: string) () {
    return `${this.url}/${route}`
  }
}

// api.ts
class Api{
    static baseUrl: string;
    static endpoints: {[K in keyof T]: any};
    constructor() {
      const { baseUrl, endpoints } = (this.constructor as typeof Api)
      const endpointInstances = Object.entries(endpoints).reduce((instances: { [name: string]: any }, [name, value]: [string, any]) => {
          instances[name] = new Endpoint(baseUrl)
        return instances
      }, {})
      Object.assign(this, endpointInstances)
    }
}

// etp/reports.ts
class Reports extends Endpoint {
  static url = 'Reports'
  getReports (designId) {
    return this.getUrl(designId)
  }
}

// etp/index.ts
class Etp extends Api {
  static baseUrl = '/planning/api/v1/'
  static endpoints = {
    reports: Reports
  }
}
export default new Etp()
```

When types are generated for this code following is found.

```
// endpoint.d.ts
export default class Endpoint {
    url: string;
    constructor(baseUrl: string);
    getUrl(route: string): string;
}

// api.d.ts
export default class Api {
    static baseUrl: string;
    static endpoints: any;
    constructor();
}

// etp/reports.d.ts
import Endpoint from '../endpoint';
export default class Reports extends Endpoint {
    static url: string;
    getReports(designId: string): string;
}

// etp/index.d.ts
import Api from '../api';
import Reports from './reports';
declare class Etp extends Api {
    static baseUrl: string;
    static endpoints: {
        reports: typeof Reports;
    };
}
declare const _default: Etp;
export default _default;
```

But code is being used as **etp.reports.getReports('1234')** which is not possible by generated types.

I want to achieve below generated types

```
// etp/index.d.ts
import Api from '../api';
import Reports from './reports';
declare class Etp extends Api {
    static baseUrl: string;
    static endpoints: {
        reports: typeof Reports;
    };
    reports: typeof Reports;
}
declare const _default: Etp;
export default _default;
```

I have tried using index signature with Generic, which is not allowed. Tried to create mixins but lost in concept.